# install latest Ubuntu on new hard drive

Tags: installation, 12.10

I have a HP Pavillion dv6-6108 that I purchased November 2011. Since then the hard drive has crashed twice. The first crash was because the laptop met the kitchen floor when I tripped over the AC cord. I upgraded to a T byte hard drive purchased at a local Depot for Office supplies and they charged an additional $100 bucks to  install Windows 7. I made a backup repair disk (14) of them and an ISO disk. I stated to get many "x not responding" messages and it started to run slow. It got to the point where it wouldn't  start up and to  get what I can off the hard drive before out fully crashes. I was able to replace the hard drive from the Office place under warranty, however, they wanted to charge again to replace the OS. I  said forget it Thu should put it back on for free because the hard drive crashed not because of my error.  They wouldn't so I figured screw  them  and Mi**o S**t I  want Ubuntu. How do I get it on my laptop with a blank hard drive.  Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to download Ubuntu 13.04 [32bit](http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download?distro=desktop&bits=32&release=latest), or [64bit](http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download?distro=desktop&bits=64&release=latest) version of Ubuntu.  Once the ISO is downloaded, you can either create a bootable DVD, or USB flash drive. For creating a DVD or USB see [Install Ubuntu 13.04](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest).  You can also use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/), to create the USB.  I would recommend that you try Ubuntu before installing just to make sure that it works OK with your hardware.

You have tagged your question with 12.10, if that's what you want to install, then you can download it [Here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/)

Make sure that you change your boot sequence to be able to boot from either the DVD or USB.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Wow, I forgot about this post. That new hard drive refused to have Windows put on it. Recovery, ISO, USB, it didn't like Windows. Even the Depot place had me meet one of there veteran, guru, tech guy, and he fought with it for a hour. I pulled a Ubuntu 9 CD out of my  laptop bag, put it in the disc reader, TA DA. started right up with the options.